# Store value into sql database in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I am new to django framework. I would like to know some of the procedure to store value into database.I created a html page with the field of firstname and lastname. I jus need to pass those value to server side and to store those value into database. I have been read doc for the django but i can't able to understand what's happening in the model.py file. Can anyone please help me to do know about this with the simple example for store value into database. please help me.. Futherly i have to be learned myself. Sorry to say if am troubling anybody who is in busy schedule.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't take time to do your homework (=> do the official tutorial), so why should we take time to answer your question ?

Comment: sry... will do it again and get back to you....

Answer (score 2):

Start with the Django Tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) and come back if you have questions after :)